# Android studio java containers/linearlayouts

Tags: java, android, containers, android-linearlayout

[image]I would like to add multiple buttons with textviews left to right in the same row and normally would set the orientation to horizontal for this but I need the vertical in order to place the textview "cash app" under the image where I need it how can I accomplish this? I heard something about container layouts but not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Code/simulator]

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to accomplish on your layout. Could you at least sketch your preferred layout?

Comment: I have updated the post with another image basically the code has to use a horizontal for left to right icons which i cannot do with the linear layout being set to vertical but it has to be vertical to place the text under each clickable src icon

Comment: Is your button and cash app text supposed to be dynamic or static (3 buttons)?

Comment: Maybe add another LinearLayout with orientation horizontal to house your cash app view.

Comment: so it will be static and the buttons depend on how many payment options i will add in the future currently im only putting two but that was an idea of what i need and i tried doing another layout but i couldent figure it out with the current code i got in the pic

Comment: You can try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can wrap your "button" in another XML layout like, let's name it `custom_view_button.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCashApp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cashapp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cash app"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your activity_layout.xml, include it like below. Take note of the `weightSum` and `layout_weight` values in order for equal widths.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <include
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_view_button"
        />
    <include
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_view_button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```